# How to change the colors of "ls" output terminal on mac osx?

Tags: macos

I would like to display executables in green, but when I use the command
`export LSCOLORS="5;c"`:

- Symbolic links stay green
- Executables continue in red
- The directories that were blue are pink

My .bash_profile :

```
 export PS1="$ "
 alias ls="ls -G"
 export LSCOLORS="5;c"
```

5 is : executable
c is : green

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you may have conflated the Linux LS_COLORS syntax with the BSD (OS X) LSCOLORS syntax and come up with a new syntax all your own.

On the Mac, and I believe on other BSDs, LSCOLORS must be a long string of pairs of letters representing colors, and it's the position of the pair in the string that specifies which file type it's for.

As you may have read in the `ls(1)` man page, the 5th pair is the pair for executables, and this is the default LSCOLORS string:

exfxcxdx**bx**egedabagacad

I've bolded the 5th pair (executables), showing that it defaults to `b` (red) for the foreground color, and `x` (default) for the background color.

So you need to change it to this:

exfxcxdx**cx**egedabagacad

Unfortunately, that makes them the same as sockets (pair 3), but whatever.

So you need to do this:

```
export LSCOLORS="exfxcxdxcxegedabagacad"
```

I tested this and it worked for me on OS X Mavericks (specifically v10.9.3).